# Making REST calls from a react component

Tags: json, rest, dom, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to make REST call from a react component and render the returned JSON data into the DOM

Here is my component

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ItemLister extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { items: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`http://api/call`) 
            .then(result=> {
                this.setState({items:result.json()});
            });
    }

    render() {        
        return(
           WHAT SHOULD THIS RETURN?
        );
    }
```

In order to bind the returned json in a DOM?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code.  The one that's probably tripping you up is the `this.setState({items:result.json()})`

Fetch's `.json()` method returns a promise, so it will need to be dealt with as async.

```
fetch(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
.then(result=>result.json())
.then(items=>this.setState({items}))
```

I don't know why `.json()` returns a promise (if anyone can shed light, I'm interested).

For the render function, here you go...

```
<ul>
   {this.state.items.map(item=><li key={item.id}>{item.body}</li>)}
</ul>
```

Don't forget the unique key!

For the other answer, there's no need to bind map.

Here it is working...

http://jsfiddle.net/weqm8q5w/6/

Comment: The fetch() function returns a Promise because of it's asynchronous nature. Ir's result will be available only after the http request is completed, so a Promise is the best solution to handle it.

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher I'm referring to why result.json() returns a promise.  Nothing about it requires execution outside of the current execution context.

Comment: .json() returns a promise because JSON.parse() is pretty slow on a large result, and because it can throw an exception if it fails.

Comment: Does .json() return a promise because it's reading from the body's stream which might not be downloaded yet?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this for your render method:

```
render() {
    var resultNodes = this.state.items.map(function(result, index) {
        return (
            <div>result<div/>
        );
    }.bind(this));
    return (
        <div>
            {resultNodes}
        </div>
    );
}
```

and don't forget to use `.bind(this)` for your `fetch(...).then()`, I don't think it could work without...

Answer (score 1):

Fetch methods will return a Promise that makes it straightforward to write code that works in an asynchronous manner:

In your case:

```
componentDidMount(){
  fetch('http://api/call')      // returns a promise object
    .then( result => result.json()) // still returns a promise object, U need to chain it again
    .then( items => this.setState({items}));
}
```

**result.json()** returns a promise, because this it works on a **response stream** and we need to process entire response first in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead. It will work: 
(You can also check the data if loaded in the console)

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: []
        }
    }

 componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://api/call')
            .then(Response => Response.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                this.setState({
                    items: res,
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
```

Then use the result stored in state during render to display as required.